# Basename gives extra operand error

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, command-substitution, basename

I 'm using the following script to merge few pcap files into one using mergecap command.
But when I run it it gives me a `'basename: extra operand /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/dcn_2014_02_04_00_11_47_598.pcap'`    error
The script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
#find last 15 files older than +5 days
FILES=$(find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap"  -mtime +5 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -15 | awk '{print $8}')

N=15
TAG1=$(basename ${FILES[0]} | sed 's/.pcap//')
TAG2=$(basename ${FILES[$N-1]} | sed 's/.pcap//')
#merge the files
mergecap -w /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/"${TAG1}_to_${TAG2}".pcap ${FILES[@]}
sudo chmod +rw /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/"${TAG1}_to_${TAG2}".pcap 
#delete originals
sudo rm  ${FILES[@]}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `awk '{print $9}'`?

Comment: @Abdul yes I thought so, but it seems like in this system $8 is giving me the file names. I tested it manually to be sure

Comment: `tag1=$(basename "${FILES[0]}" .pcap`. Remember that leaving a variable unquoted is the split+glob operator in shells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FILES=$(command)` is going to set a variable named `FILES` to a scalar that contains the output of `command`.

`${FILES[0]}` is going to be the contents of that scalar variable, in your case, a string containing 15 blank-delimited filenames, which will then be broken up into 15 fields.

It looks like you want `FILES` to be an array; for that, use `FILES=( $(command) )`  .

It's also good practice to surround shell variable accesses with double quotes - `"${FILES[0]}"` instead of `${FILES[0]}` - so that the shell doesn't break the contents into fields if there's any whitespace in them.

Comment: Note that `FILES=($(command))` is only fine when the file names don't contain whitespace or `\[?*`.